# How gaps are made between form elements in bootstrap3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://jsfiddle.net/rh2sH/

There is a little gap between `search` and `submit`. By what means is this gap made? I mean, there is no margins. Also when I tried to reduce the size of the form, it elements appear on the separate lines, which means that gap appears not because of too big size of the form.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Please include JSFiddle code on SO, to avoid future broken links (closed service, deleted fiddle...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. That's a bug of `inline-block` elements.

You can try giving `font-size:0;` to wrapper div like

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/rh2sH/3/)**

```
.navbar-form {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

OR, CSS tricks have some other [cool tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) you can try.

like

```
<ul>
  <li>
   one</li><li>
   two</li><li>
   three</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li
  ><li>two</li
  ><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!--
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, it's a nice gap and I was wondering how they did it. Appears that it's due to bug =) nice.

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this..

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left" placeholder="Search"/>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rh2sH/4/

Comment: I don't understand, what have you changed?

Comment: Added `pull-left` and put button inside `form-group`

Comment: Oh, I got `pull-left`, but missed putting inside form-group. =)